# Rails ActiveRecord: Pluck from multiple tables with same column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a simple use case:

User has many Tweets
Tweet belongs to User

And i'm trying to pluck a column name that exists on both tables. For example:

```
@tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).all.pluck(:created_at)
```

Each table has a created_at column, but the result from above returns the created_at for the tweet. How can I also pluck the user's created_at?

My workaround is below utilizing joins and selects:

```
@tweets = Tweet.joins(:user).select("users.created_at AS created_date").all
```

So how can I do this by using pluck?

Comment: Try `@tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).all.pluck(:created_at, "users.created_at")`

Comment: Hey man thanks that worked! Don't know why I didn't try that earlier...

Comment: have you tried : tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).all.pluck("user.created_at")

Comment: @JérémyButtice Hey Jeremy, so that's what I tried initially, but is should've been plural "users.created_at"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do the below

```
@tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).all.pluck(:created_at, "users.created_at")
```

And also `.all` is not necessary here as `joins/includes` fetch all ***records/associated records***. So the final query would be like below

```
@tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).pluck(:created_at, "users.created_at")
```